# Fuzzy match/multiple field match in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have the following input: `<input type="text" ng-model="query">`.

And I have the following array of data:

```
[ 
    {name: 'Ivanov Ivan', job: 'QA', grade:'Senior'},
    {name: 'Petrov Ivan', job: 'Java Developer', grade:'Middle'},
    {name: 'John Doe', job: 'JavaScript Developer', grade:'Junior'},
    {name: 'John Smith', job: 'Java Developer', grade:'Junior'},
    ...
]
```

I am using the following filter:

```
 <div ng-repeat="member in members | filter: query">{{member.name}}, {{member.job}}, {{member.grade}}</div>
```

The filter works fine for strings like `Ivan` or `QA`. However, I'd like to look up strings like `Ivan QA` or `Java Middle`.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: You should take a look on the `fuzzy` and `fuzzyBy` filters of [angular.filter](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter#fuzzy)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should try using [angular-filter](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter). It provides [fuzzy](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter#fuzzy) filter.